# Greatest number equals sum of remaining numbers

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Is it possible to place positive integers in a $100\times 101$ array so that in each row/column, the greatest number is equal to the sum of the remaining integers in that row/column?

[Source: Russian competition problem]

Comment: Is there any restriction on which numbers can be used (and whether numbers can be used more than once)?

Comment: @hardmath No, there is no restriction. In particular, numbers can be used more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & ... & 1 & 1 & 100 \\ 
1 & 1 & ... & 1 & 1 & 100 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
1 & 1 & ... & 1 & 1 & 100 \\
1 & 1 & ... & 1 & 1 & 100 \\
99 & 99 & ... & 99 & 99 & 9900
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Nice answer.  I think you could generalize this to taking the upper left $99\times 100$ subarray to be arbitrary positive numbers and then put in the row sums and column sums in the last row and column.

Comment: Indeed. This also generalizes nicely to arbitrary dimensions.